# Pipe function и try ... catch errors

Tags: javascript, функции, try-catch, pipes

Пытаюсь написать pipe function, которая, в случае отризательной проверки isFunction будет возвращать сообщение об ошибке, и которая, в случае isFunction  = true, будет производить расчет.

На данный момент в рамках текущего кода оба раза функция возвращает сообщение об ошибке:
Provided argument at position 2 is not a function! - как и должно быть
prevFn is not a function - быть не должно, т.к. при втором вызове функции const result передуется 3 функции.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как возможно устранить ошибку?

```js
function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
    return functionToCheck && {}.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}

const pipe = (value, ...funcs) => {
    try {
        let _pipe = (prevFn, nextFn) => (value) = nextFn(prevFn(value));
        let result =  funcs.reduce((prevFn, nextFn) => {
            if(!isFunction(nextFn)) {
                throw new SyntaxError('Provided argument at position 2 is not a function!');
            } else {
                return _pipe(prevFn, nextFn);
            }
        });
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message;
    }
};

const replaceUnderscoreWithSpace = (value) => value.replace(/_/g, ' ');
const capitalize = (value) =>
value
.split(' ')
.map((val) => val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1))
.join(' ');
const appendGreeting = (value) => `Hello, ${value}!`;

const error = pipe('john_doe', replaceUnderscoreWithSpace, capitalize, '');

alert(error); // Provided argument at position 2 is not a function!

const result = pipe('john_doe', replaceUnderscoreWithSpace, capitalize, appendGreeting);

alert(result); // Hello, John Doe!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю ваш код, то могу предположить две ошибки:

1. Опечатка `=` вместо `=>`. Вместо:

```js
let _pipe = (prevFn, nextFn) => (value) = nextFn(prevFn(value));
```

нужно:

```js
let _pipe = (prevFn, nextFn) => (value) => nextFn(prevFn(value));
```

2. Поскольку редьюсером возвращается функция, нужно вызвать её в самом конце последний раз. Вместо:

```js
return result;
```

нужно:

```js
return result(value);
```

```js
function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
    return functionToCheck && {}.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}

const pipe = (value, ...funcs) => {
    try {
        let _pipe = (prevFn, nextFn) => (value) => nextFn(prevFn(value));
        let result =  funcs.reduce((prevFn, nextFn) => {
            if(!isFunction(nextFn)) {
                throw new SyntaxError('Provided argument at position 2 is not a function!');
            } else {
                return _pipe(prevFn, nextFn);
            }
        });
        return result(value);
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message;
    }
};

const replaceUnderscoreWithSpace = (value) => value.replace(/_/g, ' ');
const capitalize = (value) =>
value
.split(' ')
.map((val) => val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1))
.join(' ');
const appendGreeting = (value) => `Hello, ${value}!`;

const error = pipe('john_doe', replaceUnderscoreWithSpace, capitalize, '');

alert(error); // Provided argument at position 2 is not a function!

const result = pipe('john_doe', replaceUnderscoreWithSpace, capitalize, appendGreeting);

alert(result); // Hello, John Doe!
```

Comment: спасибо большое